# Android use custom resolution

Tags: android, screen-resolution, android-virtual-device

I have problem with custom resolution in AVD.
When I have created new AVD with custom resolution, the content of my app doesnt stretch.
I also specify density but it doesnt work.

Please help me

Marcus

Comment: Can you add your XML layout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add support-screen in android Menifest file as follow.

```
     <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"
 android:xlargeScreens="true"></supports-screens>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this and this doesnt work. But when I updated Android SDK it started to work. But there I have another problem.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was solved when I updated SKD Android. But another problem occured.</br>
Now the ImageButton(src = 230x230jpg) took almost whole screen. And resolution is set on 1024x600 and abstracted LCD density to 250.</br>
I have read about density and custom resolution but I am a little confused.

Comment: If you made height and width of  ImageButton android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" make it as android:layout_height = "wrap_content" ndroid:layout_width="wrap_content". Or show me your xml file.

Comment: My layout is quite simple:   <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">  
    
  
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/khButton"  
android:layout_width = "wrap_content"  
android:layout_height= "wrap_content"  
android:src= "@drawable/menu_home"/>  
  And dimenstion of the image is 202x259 and when I took  printscreen dimension is 302x388. Its weird!

Comment: When you took print screen. Is your avd dimension is same as what you are specifying.

Comment: Hi, I am totally confused. Now when I run the emulator this is what i see:  http://postimage.org/image/27knzpbes/  The image is OK, but the surface is small. My android manifest has element: <supports-screens android:resizeable="true" 
                      android:anyDensity="true"  />

Comment: your screen looks bigger so you need to add 'android:largeScreens="true"' even it doesn'nt work then try with other options of support screen. Which android version you are using?

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I think that I had this element in configuration and it didnt work. I doesnt matter, maybe I something missed.